# Renderpartial or renderaction

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, renderpartial, renderaction, areas

have an action that generates active vacancies. The code is below;

public ViewResult OpenVacancies()
        {
            var openvacancies = db.GetActiveVacancies();
            return View(openvacancies);
        }

I want to use this list on several pages so i guess the best thing to use is html.renderaction (please correct me if i am wrong here).

Please note that the view and .ascx control are in an Area.

I then created a view by right clicking inside the action and create a .ascx and a strongly typed view of Vacancy. I chose a view content of "List".

I then added this line to the required page;

Please note that the view and .ascx control are in an Area.

The error i got is;

The type or namespace name 'Vacancy' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

the .ascx code is below;

>" %>

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>
            VacancyID
        </th>
        <th>
            JobTitle
        </th>
        <th>
            PositionID
        </th>
        <th>
            LocationID
        </th>
        <th>
            JobDescription
        </th>
        <th>
            JobConditions
        </th>
        <th>
            Qualifications
        </th>
        <th>
            RequiredSkills
        </th>
        <th>
            Certifications
        </th>
        <th>
            AdvertDate
        </th>
        <th>
            AdvertExpiryDate
        </th>
        <th>
            Status
        </th>
        <th>
            StaffLevel
        </th>
        <th>
            LineManagerEmail
        </th>
        <th>
            ApprovalFlag
        </th>
        <th>
            RequisitionDate
        </th>
    </tr>

<% foreach (var item in Model) { %>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <%= Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.VacancyID }) %> |
            <%= Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.VacancyID })%> |
            <%= Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.VacancyID })%>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(item.VacancyID) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(item.JobTitle) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(item.PositionID) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(item.LocationID) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(item.JobDescription) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(item.JobConditions) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(item.Qualifications) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(item.RequiredSkills) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(item.Certifications) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(String.Format("{0:g}", item.AdvertDate)) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(String.Format("{0:g}", item.AdvertExpiryDate)) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(item.Status) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(item.StaffLevel) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(item.LineManagerEmail) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(item.ApprovalFlag) %>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Html.Encode(String.Format("{0:g}", item.RequisitionDate)) %>
        </td>
    </tr>

<% } %>

</table>

<p>
    <%= Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create") %>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, if you simply want to reuse your view on multiple pages, you should be using a shared partial view (place it in the Shared folder) with <% Html.RenderPartial("OpenVacancies"); %>.

Second, based on your code snippet, your partial view doesn't appear to be strongly typed. Instead of

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl" %>
```

you will want something like this:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<IEnumerable<Vacancy>>" %>
```